# Many to many and one to many association between same models

Tags: ruby, orm, sequel-gem

I am creating a simple Sinatra app, using [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) for my ORM.
Most of the data revolves around users and events where:

- An event can have many users,  one of which is the "owner".
- Users can have many events, one or many of which they "own".

Here is a simplified version of my schema/model definitions:

```
class User < Sequel::Model(:users)
  many_to_many :events
  one_to_one :event
end

class Event < Sequel::Model(:events)
  many_to_many :users
  many_to_one :user
end

# provides a link between users and events
# e.g. event.users or user.events
# I am unsure how necessary this is :)
db.create_table :events_users do
  primay_key :id
  foreign_key :event_id, :events
  foreign_key :user_id, :users
end
```

This allows me to get the users attached to an event, or the events that a user is attached to, but I am struggling to express the "ownership" of an event. It seems like the following pseudocode would work:

```
my_user = User.all.first
owned_events = Event.where(user_id = my_user.user_id)
```

That leads to two questions:

1. Does the current way i'm using assocations make sense?
2. How do I express ownership of an event in terms of Sequel's association model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
class Event
  many_to_one :owner, :class=>:User
  many_to_many :users
end

class User
  one_to_many :owned_events, :class=>:Event, :key=>:owner_id
  many_to_many :events
end
```

You'll need to add `owned_id` field in `events` table.

Usage:

```
user = User.all.first
event = Event.new(:title => 'New Event')
events.add_owner(user)
event.save
another_user = User.create(:name => 'Jack')
event.add_user(another_user)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that seems to get me part of the way there, but i'm getting a noMethodError for ``add_owner`` on my event instance. I've added `owner_id` to my events table, as well as the associations mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, just wrote the code without actual testing, look here: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/association_basics_rdoc.html#label-%3Aclass and by the way get a list of available methods for event and user (`#methods`) Maybe I simple mistyped something.

Comment: I think this has to do something with how the methods are added to the class, but your answer has got me on the right track. I'll dig into this more. Thanks!